# How to save a file in azure using asp uploadFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

So my problem is that I need to read a file from a webform published in azure, the user select the file using asp.net FileUpload, but I can't read it without saving, I need to save in order to read it. How to do that using azure? Is there another way to read the file without saving it?

Thanks!

Comment: [How to download and read files from azure blob container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726115/how-to-download-and-read-files-from-azure-blob-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to save an uploaded files in order to read it. The raw contents are available as a byte stream through the [FileContents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent(v=vs.110).aspx)
 property. The [PostedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) property offers more information like the file length and content type. You can read the contents through its [InputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

[SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) simply reads the byte stream and writes the bytes to a file.

If the file is small, you can access its bytes directly through the [FileBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Otherwise you can read bytes from the stream and copy them to another stream.

You can create a CloudBlockBlob with data coming from a stream with [UploadFromStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj717380.aspx):

```
var connectionString=CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
var acct = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var client = acct.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
blob.UploadFromStream(FileUpload1.FileContents);
```

In general, file and blob operations always offer a way to use a stream. It would be impossible to work with large files otherwise

Comment: So you are saying that it's possible to read that file without saving it just using the FileUpload properties?

Comment: Yes,as Pangiotis Kanavos said that **FileUpload.FileContent** can be used to blob to upload the file to Azure. And the **FileConent** is a Stream object that points to a file, Azure blob supports to use stream to upload file. Please have a try.`blob.UploadFromStream(FileUpload1.FileContent);`